# What is the python equivalent to perl "a".."azc"

Tags: python, perl, list

In perl, to get a list of all strings from "a" to "azc", to only thing to do is using the range operator:

```
perl -le 'print "a".."azc"'
```

What I want is a list of strings:

```
["a", "b", ..., "z", "aa", ..., "az" ,"ba", ..., "azc"]
```

I suppose I can use `ord` and `chr`, looping over and over, this is simple to get for "a" to "z", eg:

```
>>> [chr(c) for c in range(ord("a"), ord("z") + 1)]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

But a bit more complex for my case, here.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generator version:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import product

def letterrange(last):
    for k in range(len(last)):
        for x in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=k+1):
            result = ''.join(x)
            yield result
            if result == last:
                return
```

**EDIT:** @ihightower asks in the comments:

> I have no idea what I should do if I want to print from 'b' to 'azc'.

So you want to start with something other than `'a'`. Just discard anything before the start value:

```
def letterrange(first, last):
    for k in range(len(last)):
        for x in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=k+1):
            result = ''.join(x)
            if first:
                if first != result:
                    continue
                else:
                    first = None
            yield result
            if result == last:
                return
```

Comment: yeah ! Definitely good (can't vote as I'm only 11 reputation, but sound right !)

Comment: Could be great answer... But, How does one use this... As a newbie... I have no idea what I should do if I want to print from 'b' to 'azc'. I repeat from letter "b" to the letter "azc". The function may be good... but as a beginner I have no idea how I could use it to do the actual work and print.

Answer (score 4):

A suggestion purely based on iterators:

```
import string
import itertools

def string_range(letters=string.ascii_lowercase, start="a", end="z"):
    return itertools.takewhile(end.__ne__, itertools.dropwhile(start.__ne__, (x for i in itertools.count(1) for x in itertools.imap("".join, itertools.product(letters, repeat=i)))))

print list(string_range(end="azc"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the product call in itertools, and ascii_letters from string.

```
from string import ascii_letters
from itertools import product

if __name__ == '__main__':
    values = []
    for i in xrange(1, 4):
        values += [''.join(x) for x in product(ascii_letters[:26], repeat=i)]

    print values
```

Comment: It should be `ascii_lowercase`, and you haven't yet accounted for stopping at 'azc'.

Comment: hmm, thanks, here I can have a list of string from a to zzz. So I will do a second loop to copy the items from the first loop to the second one, and stop while encountering the "end" string.

I'll answer my question with a complete code sample. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way to do it, though you need a conversion function:

```
for i in xrange(int('a', 36), int('azd', 36)):
    if base36encode(i).isalpha():
        print base36encode(i, lower=True)
```

And here's your function (thank you [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36)):

```
def base36encode(number, alphabet='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', lower=False):
    '''
    Convert positive integer to a base36 string.
    '''
    if lower:
        alphabet = alphabet.lower()
    if not isinstance(number, (int, long)):
        raise TypeError('number must be an integer')
    if number < 0:
        raise ValueError('number must be positive')

    # Special case for small numbers
    if number < 36:
        return alphabet[number]

    base36 = ''
    while number != 0:
        number, i = divmod(number, 36)
        base36 = alphabet[i] + base36

    return base36
```

I tacked on the lowercase conversion option, just in case you wanted that.

Answer (score 1):

I generalized the accepted answer to be able to start middle and to use other than lowercase:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase
from itertools import product

def letter_range(first, last, letters=ascii_lowercase):
    for k in range(len(first), len(last)):
        for x in product(letters, repeat=k+1):
            result = ''.join(x)
            if len(x) != len(first) or result >= first:
                yield result
                if result == last:
                    return
print list(letter_range('a', 'zzz'))
print list(letter_range('BA', 'DZA', ascii_uppercase))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def strrange(end):
    values = []
    for i in range(1, len(end) + 1):
        values += [''.join(x) for x in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=i)]
    return values[:values.index(end) + 1]
```

Comment: Major issues with this: 1) Use of `xrange` instead of `range`.  `xrange` no longer has any advantage over `range`, since `range` is a generator and doesn't pre-generate the result list.  Thus `xrange` is deprecated, and IIRC, not even in Python 3. 2) Constructing `endvalues` from `values` when you could have just used `list.index()` and a slice operation. 3) This isn't how you mark questions as answered on SO.

Comment: @Mike, `xrange` is still required in Python 2.7, which was released less than 2 weeks ago.  `range` still returns a list.

Comment: I've updated this one to use slices and index(). Also removed the wrapping text.